# EF Core ToString() Method Causing Exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

So basically my code is breaking over below line

```
var saleOrderIds= saleOList.Select(saleOList => saleOList.SaleOrderId.ToString()).ToList();
```

At the above code following exception is occuring

System.InvalidOperationException
comparisonType: CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of the 'string.Equals' overload with a 'StringComparison' parameter is not supported.

The Same Line Was Working Fine In .Net Framework

How to resolve the issue , is there any alternate way to achieve the result in EfCore,.Net6 ?

Comment: *"The Same Line Was Working Fine In .Net Framework"* - depends, if its in-memory enumerables it will work just fine. on `IQueryable` however, it behave differently. as a workaround, you can `ToList()` the `saleOList` first then `Select()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
var saleOrderIds= saleOList.Select(saleOList => saleOList.SaleOrderId).ToList().Select(x => x.ToString());
```

That said, I wonder if this is an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Normally, converting integer primary keys into strings is a bad idea. Why are you doing that?

Comment: actually we are migrating project form .net framework to .net core , this line was intended to catch all the saleorderids as a list for further operation over it

Comment: You didn't explain why your further operation is using strings. I've worked with coworkers in the past who've written code like this, and they're usually mixing presentation tier stuff with data access layer logic, and the list of strings frequently gets passed back into the data access layer for "further operations", causing massive performance issues. Good luck.